# Obscure unsafe code behaviour in c#

Tags: c#, unsafe

Recently I wrote some trees and want to try unsafe code. Finally I do all without unsafe but find some obscure (for me) places in this code (for shorter code I delete all logic so all code looks quite pointless):

```
public static void Main() {
        EqClass a = new EqClass();
        a.AddElement(2, new record(3)); // *place1*
                    ...
            }
    unsafe struct node {
        public node* next;
        public record Value;
        public node(record value) {
            this = new node();
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }
    struct record {
        public int a;
        public record(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
    }
    unsafe class EqClass {
        node*[] last = new node*[3];
        public void AddElement(int classIndex, record element) {
            node a = new node(element);
            node* newNode = &a;
            last[classIndex]->next = newNode; // *place2*
        }
    }
```

In **place2** all is all right but when method `AddElement` ends, in last[2](where we put an element) unexpectedly appear some garbage. But why? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this using unsafe code, instead of managed code?

Comment: Yes, I did it with classes and managed code finally, but it is very interesting for me why this code doesn't work? I couldn't find a mistake...

Comment: There is no need to use unsafe code to implement this at all.  You're just trying to use C/C++ inside a .NET program and circumventing all the type-safety features inherent to .NET in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **not** what `unsafe` and `*` is for. Seriously: do not do this. What you are doing here is essentially references. For that: use a `class`, not a `struct`. This is going to hurt you very very very badly otherwise.

Also: this is not what `struct` is for. Looking at a mutable `struct` like this tells me in an instant that you aren't appreciating what `struct` is intended to do.

If you want to know where nonsense values are coming from: the pointers aren't to pinned locations. The fix to this is not "oh, so I need to pin them". It is "use references, not pointers".

Comment: This should really be a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: @Servy no, sorry, but it shouldn't. The answer in this case is simply "you're fundamentally doing it wrong"

Comment: And it will be yet slower, yes? I understand, but it was interesting to try unsafe code and when I see that it works quite strange for me, I was interested, why?

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov the "quite strange" is most likely due to GC compaction and pointers to unpinned memory locations. Don't assume classes will be slower. Besides: it doesn't matter how fast broken code runs: it is broken.

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov Speed is irrelevant when one solution doesn't even work.  Performance is only worth comparing between solutions that provide valid output.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I assume that classes will be faster as they don't broke GC's work.

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov allocations are not as expensive as you might think. GC only gets expensive if you have a **very large** number of objects. And yes, in that scenario on option is to use an array of structs rather than objects. However, that doesn't mean using pointers. There are ways of working inside this; for example as discussed here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/assault-by-gc.html

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov you might be interested that we *do* use `unsafe` inside that - but not for the item-level values; more, we use `unsafe` to use "fixed buffers" inside the struct, rather than an array.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you, so unsafe code in c# (without work with native code) is for fixed buffers mostly?

Comment: @EvgeniyKluchikov That is one use. Talking to genuinely unmanaged memory is another. Performing bitwise abuse is a third - for example, in my web-sockets server I use `unsafe` code to perform frame masking on a `byte[]` 8 bytes at a time, by briefly talking to the `byte[]` as though it were a `long*`; note that this uses the `fixed` keyword which pins the array for the duration of the scoped block. I also use it in some serialization code to thunk between `double`/`long` and `float`/`int`. But: it isn't for what you are doing.